# Example of a pair of closed, non-empty, disjoint subsets of R with sequences $\{x_n\}, \{y_n\}$ where $\lim_{n\to\infty}|x_n - y_n| = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I got this question on a homework assignment and I've been thinking about it for at least an hour and have been unable to think of an example of such disjoint closed sets of that have points that approach an arbitrarily small distance from each other. My current thought is that both sets need to be not compact, and both sets will need to approach some infinite value and the sequences will need to have a decreasing derivative. A current idea are the sets $A:=\{\ln(x) : x$ is odd $\}$, $B:=\{\ln(x) : x$ : is even $\}$, as the derivative of $\ln(x)$ decreases as $x$ gets greater, with the sequences being $\{x_n\} : = \{\ln(2n - 1)\}$ and $\{y_n\} := \{\ln(2n)\}$ but I'm not sure that this works. Could someone check this answer for me or give me a hint to push me in the right direction?

Comment: @Deif not closed. You need something that's unbounded.

Comment: @Deif Neither of those is closed.

Comment: I thought about that, but wouldn't $A$ and $B$ not be closed then, because 0 is an accumulation point of both sets, but not included, meaning $A$ and $B$ do not equal their closure.

Comment: You can modify @deif example to make it unbounded and closed. Just consider adding $n$

Comment: You are correct. My bad.

Comment: Oh, I just saw it, yes, your example works as well. $\ln(2n)-\ln(2n-1) = \ln(1-1/2n)\to \ln(1) = 0$

Comment: You can take $x_n=n$ and $y_n = n+\frac{1}{2n}$

Comment: Try $A= \{ (x,y) \mid e^x \le y \}$, $B =\{ (x,y) \mid -e^x \ge y \}$.

Comment: @copper.hat This is an eaxmple in $\mathbb  R^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example is correct. Since $\ln x \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$, both $A$ and $B$ are closed.

We have
$$\lvert x_n - y_n \rvert = y_n -x_n = \ln(2n) - \ln (2n-1) = \ln \frac{2n}{2n-1}$$
and therefore
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \lvert x_n - y_n \rvert = \lim_{n \to \infty} \ln \frac{2n}{2n-1} = 0$$
because $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2n}{2n-1} = 1$ and $\ln$ is continuous.

Alternatively you can take any strictly increasing sequence $(x_n)$  with $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n  = \infty$. Then $A= \{x_n \mid  n \in \mathbb N\}$ is easily seen to be closed. Now choose any sequence $(y_n)$ with $x_n < y_n < \min(x_{n+1},x_n + \frac 2 n)$. Then $(y_n)$ is strictly increasing with $\lim_{n \to \infty} y_n  = \infty$. Hence $B = \{y_n \mid  n \in \mathbb N\}$ is closed and by construction disjoint from $A$.

Clearly $\lim_{n \to \infty} \lvert x_n - y_n \rvert = 0$.

As an example take $x_n = n$ and $y_n = n + \frac 1 n$.